# Span Background Over Entire Intro Page

Tags: java, eclipse

I've created my own welcome page for the `org.eclipse.ui.intro.config` extension point. This package has a background image I want to stretch over the entire view.

So I tried this:

```
body {
    background-image: url("./background.jpg");
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

And the image gets shown, but it's tiled. I also tried `percentage 100% 100%` and `contain` as `background-size` as [found here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp), but to no avail.

(If I open the XHTML file inside the browser, it works as it should.)

How do I make the background image cover an intro page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to use the program arguments `org.eclipse.swt.browser.DefaultType` and `org.eclipse.swt.browser.IEVersion` to steer clear away from the Internet Explorer (see [How do I specify the default type of native renderer that is used by the Browser?](https://www.eclipse.org/swt/faq.php#browserspecifydefault)).